# Question about determining the kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> $\ker \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
> -4 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}\right) $
>
> The solution is
>
> $=span\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0 \\ -4 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}\right\}=span\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

But how do I get there? Do I have to solve a linear equation system or what is the right solution approach?
Another example would be

> $\ker \left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
> 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 3 & 0 & 7 \\
> \end{array}\right)$
>
> $=span\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -7 \\ -3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

Could someone explain me how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every matrix $A$ of order $m\times n$ over a field $F$ has an associated linear map $T\colon F^n\to F^m$ defined by $T(X)=AX$ which is called the matrix transformation induced by $A$. When you are asked about the kernel of $A$, it refers to the kernel of this map. Basically, you're to find the solutions $X$ of the equation $AX=0$

Comment: The usual way to compute the kernel of a matrix is to row-reduce it, which indeed corresponds to solving an associated system of equations.  How much do you know about linear algebra?  Do you understand what I mean by "row-reduction" or "row-echelon form"?  Are you currently working from a textbook?  If so, which one?  Answering these questions would help us write an answer that addresses your needs.

Comment: Yes, I understand “row-reduction” and “row-echelon-Form”. I am currently in the first semester of a computer science degree in Germany. I just didn’t fully understand how to get the span from the matrix. I tried solving the equation system but I wasn’t able to get the right solution. Could someone show me the necessary steps to get the solution above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We try to solve $Ax=0$.

The matrices that you show have rank $3$ and nullity $1$.

Identify the non-pivot column. Suppose $x_4=4t$ (chosen in this form to have integer), then we have

From the first row,
$$-4x_1+6(4t)=0 \iff x_1=6t$$
From the third row,
$$x_2=0$$
From the last row,

$$x_3+4t=0 \iff x_3=-4t$$

Hence the solution must be of the form of

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 6t \\ 0\\ -4t\\ 4t\end{bmatrix}=t\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 0\\ -4\\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

For the second example, you might like to further reduce the matrix first and identify the non-pivot column, they are the free variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. What are the non-pivot columns? Are these the linear dependent columns? I am not familiar with the term, as I come from Germany.

Comment: Those columns without the leadings ones in REF.